# Alamofire cant download / request anything on real iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

my app using Alamofire with HTTPS , Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES ,

Everything work perfectly in IOS Simulator ( iPhoneX ,11.2 ) Buth when testing with real iPhone device , things gone wrong.

Nothing loaded from Alamofire.request The completion closure never get called ( responseJSON(completionHandler: ) Nothing inside getting called

Any idea how to solve this ???? thank mate

URL

```
"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%ld&lon=%ld&APPID="
```

Codes

```
func weatherReq ( range : weatherRange ){
        let aa = locationNow?.coordinate.latitude
        let bb = locationNow?.coordinate.longitude

        if let myurl = WebFetcher_Helper.weatherURLby(Long: aa, Lat: bb, timeRange: range){

        Alamofire.request(myurl).responseJSON(completionHandler: { [weak self] (response) in
            if let myErr  = response.error{
                // some error occur
                print("ERROR Fetching JSON")
                print(myErr.localizedDescription)
            }

            switch range {
            case .daily:
                if let res = response.data {
                    self?.dailyDisplay(rawData: res)
                }
            case .weekly:
                if let res = response.data {
                    self?.weeklyDisplay(rawData: res)
                }
            }
          })

        }
     }
```

Comment: put your code here as well

Comment: please paste your code here..

Comment: just done indent

Comment: @Memexeiei are you getting latitude and longitude?

Comment: got both , everything work perfectly inside Simulator , but not real device (iPhone 7 , 11.2)

Comment: Found strange behavior , im using NSNotification to run tableview.reload()  method , im posting NSNotification inside completion (GDC mainqueue) of NSURLSession Data task.    In simulator , everything went well .  In real iPhone the Notification.post() never get called ?????